# GitHub Personal Access Token Private repo scope

Tags: github, netlify, netlify-cli

I am currently trying out Netlify function and using Netlify-cli to setup the CD. In the authorizing options, I picked the GitHub Personal Access Token and I want to know if the `Full control of private repositories` scope will include the private repos in the organization that I am apart of as I don't want it to access the repos in the organization.

Answer (score 0):

The scope has a few implications and you should probably look at a user specific role for setting up access tokens without giving access to a user (yourself) as the owner of the org repositories you have.

Create a (machine) user that has access to only the one repository or repositories (private) that would limit the access to these repositories or an organization repository. Since private tokens have read/write access this is a prudent approach to making sure you're limiting access to other repositories using the token.

If at a later time this changes on Github, this will no longer be needed. It is the approach I have used to limit my exposure to a leaked token or access.

Comment: So what you are suggesting me is to create a new account, give that account the access to write and read that 1 private repo in my account. Then give access to my new account to netlify, and in that way, netlify would only have access to that 1 specific private repo. 

Hope I understand that correctly.